# Procurar um tipo de arquivo dentro de varias pastas e guardar a hieraquia

Tags: python

Eu tenho a seguinte situação, tenho uma pasta que contem varios projetos, dentro de cada projeto tem uma pasta automação, e dentro de pasta automação varias pastas tipo:
**Game_play**, **Menu**, **Settings**

e dentro dessas pastas tem a pasta com o codigo python.

Meu problema é, como eu faria para pegar e listar cada pasta?

Exemplo

Lista de **Game_play**: `test01.py`, `test02.py`, `test03.py`
Lista de **Menu**: `test01.py`, `test02.py`, `test03.py`

assim que eu tentei:

```
import glob

lista = []:
for air in glob.glob('.py'):
   lista.append(air)

print(lista)
```

mas só lista os `.py` da pasta final.

Como eu poderia fazer pra ele percorrer todas as pastas?
No final eu vou converter a lista pra `json`, mas essa parte eu já aprendi fazer

<sup>Me desculpem qualquer coisa, é meu primeiro post e agora que estou aprendendo python.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

A partir do Python 3.5 há um novo pacote na biblioteca padrão do Python, chamado `pathlib`. Nela, a classe `Path` permite vários tipos de operação com diretórios ou arquivos, inclusive atalhos para leitura e escrita direta de arquivos. Na verdade, todos os métodos e formas de lidar com arquivos que estão espalhados nas versões anteriores do Python nos módulos `os`, `os.path`, `glob`, `shutils` além do próprio `open` podem ser centralizados em médotos ou atributos do `pathlib.Path`. Não deixe de ver a documentação em https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Entre os métodos do `pathlib.Path`, há o  `glob`, que é mais poderoso que o glob do `glob.glob` - uma vez que ele não só faz o match de nomes de arquivos, como também já retorna objetos `Path`, prontos para serem usados em qualquer situação - e dos quais pode se ver tanto o caminho completo, quanto o nome, ou qualquer parte do caminho para o arquivo.
Esse método também permite, como o `glob.glob` o uso de dois "**" para busca em todos os subdiretórios correspondentes -

```
import pathlib

lista = list(pathlib.Path(".").glob("**/*py"))
```

Dentro da variável lista, você terá um objeto "Path" para *cada*  arquivo .py a partir do diretório atual (indicado pelo diretório inicial "." na expressão).

Se precisar só das pastas que contém os arquivos .py, e não dos arquivos em si, o atributo "parent" de cada objeto "Path" é um "Path" para a pasta onde está o arquivo - pode-se usar uma comprehension para obter o "parent" de todas os arquivos obtidos com a expressão acima e coloca-los num conjunto (objeto do tipo `set`), que elinina duplicatas. Como além disso você vai transformar em Json, e não abrir as pastas em si, é importante transformar esse conjunto contendo `Path`s em uma simples lista contendo strings ( `str`), já que a serialização pra Json não aceita nem `set`s, nem `Path`s.

Parece complicado, mas o código é só esse:

```
lista = list(set(str(path.parent) for path in pathlib.Path(".").glob("**/*py")))
```

(ou seja, para cada Path localizado com o glob, extrair o .parent, e transformar em str, e essa str será uma item de um conjunto - ao final da operação, transformar o `set` de volta em uma lista (`list`).

Python também aceita criar conjuntos automaticamente nas comprehensions, com o uso de `{ }` em vez da chamada pra `set`:

```
lista = list({str(path.parent) for path in pathlib.Path(".").glob("**/*py")})
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, quando preciso acessar meus arquivos 'xlsx' no diretório, uso o código abaixo, talvez não seja o que você quer mas já é uma luz...

```
import os
# vendo a lista de arquivos no diretorio
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
#files
# Selecionando os arquivos 'xlsx' de interesse através  do nome do arquivo 
#padronizado
files_xls = [ f for f in files if f[:3] == 'Loc']
```

Comment: eu sempre gostei de de combinar `listdir` com `if` mais do que do `glob.glob` também - mas experimente o novo  `pathlib` e o método `iterdir()` dos objetos  `Path`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import os.path
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import json
import shutil
import pathlib

pasta = 'D:/tfdia/OneDrive/Automação/Projects/Games/Virgo'
version = '3'
number = 1
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
chdir(pasta)
Criar pasta casao não exista
not.exists('Game_play'):

makedirs('Game_play/tc001.air')

#entra na pasta onde vou criar o Python
chdir('Game_play/tc001.air')

#Criar arquivo python
('tc001.py').touch()

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
chdir(pasta)
#Criar pasta casao não exista
 not.exists('Menu'):
    makedirs('Menu/tc001.air')

#entra na pasta onde vou criar o Python
chdir('Menu/tc001.air')

#Criar arquivo python
('tc001.py').touch()

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
chdir(pasta)
#Criar pasta casao não exista
 not.exists('Settings'):
    makedirs('Settings/tc001.air')

#entra na pasta onde vou criar o Python
chdir('Settings/tc001.air')

#Criar arquivo python
('tc001.py').touch()

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
chdir(pasta)
#Criar pasta casao não exista
 not.exists('Setup'):
    makedirs('Setup/tc001.air')

#entra na pasta onde vou criar o Python
chdir('Setup/tc001.air')

#Criar arquivo python
('tc001.py').touch()

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#listar as pastas e arquivos
chdir(pasta)
lista = list({str(path.parent) for path in pathlib.Path(".").glob("**/*py")})

list_data = [version, number, lista]

dictionary ={
    'Numero Json+': number,
    'Version': version,
    'list': list_data
}

print('pasta :', json.dumps(dictionary, indent=2))

def escrever_json(lista):
with open('testes.json', 'w') as air:
    json.dump(    , air)

def carregar_json(arquivo):
with open('testes.json', 'r') as cg:
    return json.load(cg)

escrever_json(dictionary)
```

Comment: pasta : {
  "Numero Json+": 1,
  "Version": "Sprint 3",
  "list": [
    "Sprint 3",
    1,
    [
      "Setup\\tc001.air",
      "Settings\\tc001.air",
      "Game_play\\tc001.air",
      "Menu\\tc001.air"
    ]
  ]
}

Process finished with exit code 0